# LinqPad with EF 7.0

Tags: entity-framework, linqpad, entity-framework-core

Was anybody successful in using LINQPad with EF 7? When I generate DLL, and select it in "EF with DBContext" screen, I am getting an error `Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=6.0.0`

Is it me or is it not (yet) supported?

Comment: It is supported in the next version 5.05.02

Answer (score 2):

Its not fully supported but basic querying can be made, a LinqPad version above 5.06 it's preferred (http://www.linqpad.net/download.aspx), then:
- Add Connection
- Use "View More Drivers" button at the end of the dialog
- Select EF7

Comment: When i select the dll that has my context class, it says that it cant find any dependent assemblies. Any tips on how to get around this?

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Again, I have the same, and worked around it by cross compiling my EF layer (library) across .NET 4.6 and Standard, then reference 4.6 in LinqPad.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Free Version of LinqPad**

You would need to add the referenced DLLs to your output folder. So, if your generated DLL is in `...\artifacts\bin\MyWebApp\Debug\dnx451`, then go into `C:\Users\{USERNAME}\.dnx\packages` and find the relevant folder for the referenced DLL, in this case, this would be `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures` and traverse that folder structure to find the most suitable DLL. Copy that to your output folder. Repeat for each referenced DLL. *I found it useful to create a little batch file to do the copy for me, in case I need to do this again in future. I don't know if there is a simpler way, but for now, this is what I did*

**Option 2: Paid Version of LinqPad**

Create a local NuGet package source (from the `Add NuGet` window, click on `Settings` on the bottom left corner, and for the `Source` setting, put the folder where you want to put your personal NuGet packages `e.g. C:\Nuget\Personal` and give a name. Copy the output *.nupkg files after your build into this folder. Now, these DLLs (ahem... NuGet packages) will appear when you switch from the official NuGet sources to your local repo. When you add one of these to your project, LinqPad will download all the necessary references from NuGet.

Comment: I have the free version of LinqPad and followed these instructions. I added serveral dlls from the packages folder until I was able to connect to the context. However, when I click on the test button I get an error related to a missing dll named System.Interactive.Async version 1.2.0.0. Is anyone else get this error or know where to get this dll?

Comment: I followed this process as well... and added a reference to each DLL it complained about... but it did not work. I have a paid LinqPad version, and I sent an email to the given support email but never got any feedback. So in the end, I just ditched the whole idea of using EF7 with LinqPad 5.06 for the moment